# Alexa a/c linking for multiple skills using same authorisation server URI issue

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

We have developed 2 skills, one Smart Home skill and one Custom skill. Both skills require a/c linking and used the same authorisation server URI. Everything works fine when we link a/c for both of them but when it refresh the access token after expiry period, one of the skill randomly gives a/c linking error.

We are not sure how the access token and refresh token is managed internally. But what seems to be happening here is - whichever skills refresh the access token first, continue to work fine and other one might be trying to refresh access token using the same old refresh token which was already used once?

Can anyone please clarify if

1. Can we use same authorisation server URI to perform a/c linking for more than one skill?
2. If yes then are we missing out something due to which we are seeing the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle, we were able to find out the root cause. Its possible to use same authorisation URI for more than one skills. But we should use separate pair of `Client ID` and `Client Secret` for each skill. It helps each skill to have their own set of `access_token` and `refresh_token` instead of sharing the same tokens among all skills.

In our case we have created separate services in our platform to get separate pair of `Client ID` and `Client Secret`. After updating the a/c linking configuration with the same, both skills working fine.